# SSZipArchive fails to unzip Google Books epubs

Tags: swift, unzip, epub, ssziparchive

My code executes this sequence:

1. `Epub` download request
2. Unzipping using `SSZipArchive`

For example `e-book` from this link unzips successfully:

https://www.z-epub.com/electronic-book/3633

E-book from `Google Books` however doesn't:

https://books.google.it/books/download/Life_and_Times_of_Frederick_Douglass.epub?id=fFTcLFXId-wC&hl=&output=epub&source=gbs_api

I get this error:

> Error Domain=SSZipArchiveErrorDomain Code=-1 "failed to open zip file" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=failed to open zip file}

Here's an interesting thing, same `Google Books e-book` is unzipped successfully if I add it to app's `Bundle` or import it through `fileImporter` (SwiftUI).

I'm making assumption that this issue might be related with file permissions. I might be wrong though. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what the files look like whet they are downloaded

```
$ $ wget -nv https://www.z-epub.com/electronic-book/3633
2022-10-17 14:35:23 URL:https://www.z-epub.com/electronic-book/3633 [753686/753686] -> "3633" [1]
```

What have we downloaded -- that appears to be an epub file, and it is also a valid zip file

```
$ file 3633 
3633: EPUB document

$ unzip -l 3633
Archive:  3633
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       20  2022-09-07 00:36   mimetype
        0  2022-09-07 00:36   META-INF/
      244  2022-09-07 00:36   META-INF/container.xml
     2535  2022-09-07 00:36   content.opf
   280948  2022-09-07 00:36   index-1_1.jpg
    36675  2022-09-07 00:36   index-3_1.jpg
    30045  2022-09-07 00:36   index-420_1.jpg
    96011  2022-09-07 00:36   index-424_1.jpg
     9528  2022-09-07 00:36   index-424_2.jpg
     9563  2022-09-07 00:36   index-424_3.jpg
    12090  2022-09-07 00:36   index-424_4.jpg
    15663  2022-09-07 00:36   index-426_1.jpg
   138226  2022-09-07 00:36   index_split_000.html
   134177  2022-09-07 00:36   index_split_001.html
   136279  2022-09-07 00:36   index_split_002.html
   135831  2022-09-07 00:36   index_split_003.html
   135266  2022-09-07 00:36   index_split_004.html
   132119  2022-09-07 00:36   index_split_005.html
   265375  2022-09-07 00:36   index_split_006.html
     3634  2022-09-07 00:36   index_split_007.html
       58  2022-09-07 00:36   page_styles.css
      730  2022-09-07 00:36   stylesheet.css
     7769  2022-09-07 00:36   toc.ncx
---------                     -------
  1582786                     23 files
```

Now for the document from Google Books.

```
$ wget -nv 'https://books.google.it/books/download/Life_and_Times_of_Frederick_Douglass.epub?id=fFTcLFXId-wC&hl=&output=epub&source=gbs_api'
2022-10-17 14:36:06 URL:https://books.google.it/books/download/Life_and_Times_of_Frederick_Douglass.epub?id=fFTcLFXId-wC&hl=it&source=gbs_api&capid=AFLRE71pa6m6U4kyhfqVhaMlSaPP4IhFhRDadl4EH8uPhMSCrD2HznTfJdCsQbhqdFjma8lxUITKJ7EAPw2Dvpo2J5lpmvDi6w&continue=https://books.google.it/books/download/Life_and_Times_of_Frederick_Douglass.epub%3Fid%3DfFTcLFXId-wC%26hl%3Dit%26output%3Depub%26source%3Dgbs_api [13867] -> "Life_and_Times_of_Frederick_Douglass.epub?id=fFTcLFXId-wC&hl=&output=epub&source=gbs_api" [1]
```

what have we downloaded?

```
$ file Life_and_Times_of_Frederick_Douglass.epub\?id\=fFTcLFXId-wC\&hl\=\&output\=epub\&source\=gbs_api 
Life_and_Times_of_Frederick_Douglass.epub?id=fFTcLFXId-wC&hl=&output=epub&source=gbs_api: HTML document, ISO-8859 text, with very long lines (11433)
```

That isn't an epub file. When I went to the URL in my browser, I found a page in Italian that needed user input. Below image has the English translation.

[image]

When I dowloaded the epb file manually from that site it looked fine.

Are you doing anything in your code to bypass the form?

Comment: You're right, somehow the 2FA form was not mandatory after several successful bypasses, therefore I forgot about it. In any case, I'm not familiar with bypassing such forms. I can do a research however, is this form called captcha?

Comment: Yes, it is a captcha

Comment: Thank you, I did some research and got nowhere. One thing I tried was to implement webview within the app and enter the code manually, but that got me nowhere. I'm lost with this idea. Anything you can get me going on to?

Comment: Sorry no. Suggest creating a new question specifically about bypassing the capcha